# What are some good podcasts to listen to?

Tags: analysis, learning, tactics, recommendations

I'm an intermediate player, and I practice chess tactics and play regularly. I'm looking for a good podcast or two to listen to during my day. I don't care if it's a podcast that discusses chess news, tactics, or does analysis of games, I just need it to hold my attention for a while. Preferably something available on an Android or PC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Full English Breakfast](http://thefeb.podbean.com) by Stephen Gordon, Laurence Trent, and Macauley Peterson was always fun. It was been discontinued 2 years ago but it might still be worth a look.

Comment: This answer is now 7 years old, and the podcast has not been resumed. Further, when I tried to listen, it felt very out of date to me.

Answer (score 6):

Ben Johnson produces a weekly chess podcast called "[The Perpetual Chess Podcast](https://www.perpetualchesspod.com/new-blog/)".

The format is roughly an hour long interview with a personality from the chess world. As well as top grandmasters he also interviews educators, writers, chess politicians and publishers.

Recent interviewees include GMs Irina Krush, David Navara, Josh Friedel and Paco Vallejo, author GM Genna Sosonko, co-founder of Chessbase Frederic Friedel and chess politicians running in the upcoming FIDE presidential elections GM Nigel Short and IM Malcolm Pein.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what you may have asked for but sort of. Here the host interviews a celeb over a game of chess. http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b04njsks/episodes/downloads

Answer (score 3):

You can get a lot out of the Banter Blitz videos (served by YouTube) by [Chess24](https://chess24.com/en/live/video/c54f29aeec-banter-blitz-with-jan-gustafsson). The link shows an example by GM Jan Gustafsson, but there are other masters offering similar material. Much of the content is free.

You said you weren't particular about the content, but you might find it interesting to know that these videos involve the master explaining what's going on during a blitz game they're playing, and what they're thinking while they play. As a result, you will get advice about openings, learn to spot the kinds of mistakes their opponents make, pick up some endgame theory, and even get some in-game commentary on tournaments, personalities, and history.  A very enriching experience, overall.

I find the format where one game at a time is played, start-to-finish, more enriching than the simul display formats that are offered elsewhere, such as at ICC.  For one thing, in the simul format the master is often playing as fast as possible, with very little time for talk. On the other hand, in the one-at-a-time format, the master can advise/warn/speculate/muse/babble during the opponent's think time. I find that the content is just richer with this format.

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for Spanish podcasts:

- [El Rincón del Ajedrez](http://www.ivoox.com/suscripciones_jb_3371285_1.html), 30-40 minutes each, an interesting podcast focused on chess culture, with interviews, chess history, book reviews and so on with Manuel Azuaga. It used to be weekly, although lately it is done every 15 days (maybe summer holidays).
- [COOLtura de Ajedrez](http://www.ivoox.com/suscripciones_jb_3501760_1.html), another good podcast, 1 hour each, with chess news and some good interviews. Chess news are mainly about catalan chess, but major national and international tournaments are treated too.
- [Xarxa de Mat](http://www.ivoox.com/suscripciones_jb_3371286_1.html), another weekly 1 hour podcast very similar to COOLtura de Ajedrez, but in this case language is Catalan.

Comment: Thanks, these work perfectly as I speak Spanish. Two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 2):

This could use some updating. With chess becoming more popular during the SAR-COV-2 pandemic and also from the ***Queen's Gambit*** miniseries,  chess podcasting has exploded in the past couple years.

Already mentioned in another answer, the [Perpetual Chess Podcast](https://www.perpetualchesspod.com/) is the best podcast I know of that is currently (December 2021) in continued production. It has now been going for over 5 years, with weekly interview pods. There are also separate book reviews most months. Recently there were special releases during the World Championship match.

US Chess has four different podcasts:

- [Lady's knight](https://ladiesknight.org/): features women in chess
- [Cover Stories](https://coverstorieswithchesslife.podbean.com/): discusses the cover story from that month's issue of ***Chess Life***
- [Underground](https://chessunderground.podbean.com/): "explores eccentricities, peculiarities, and theoretical novelties."
- [One move at a time](https://onemoveatatime.podbean.com/): about people and organizations promoting chess in the US (and US Chess' mission)

[Chess Journeys](https://open.spotify.com/show/1kNbZLQE6JvbAyfOlv7ZNY) is another podcast I enjoy regularly. It is a series of interviews with adult improvers of all levels.

[Premier Chess Podcast](https://premierchess.buzzsprout.com/): TBH, I find this one uneven. Sometimes the guests are - at best - only tangentially related to chess. I don't listen a lot, and usually skip the episodes that don't look chess related.

Another one I have listened to is [The Chess Pit](https://www.chesspitpod.com/), where - as their tag line goes - "three guys talk about chess ... occasionally". They also covered the Carlsen-Nepomniachtchi match, with discussions of the games on a daily basis. (Update: As of early July, 2023, The Chess Pit hasn't been producing new shows regularly for the past several months, although they did produce some shows during the Ding-Nepomniachtchi match. As such, I've moved it to the bottom of the list.)

There are many more, but in the interest of time and space I will stop here.